# c++ log library with Debug Mode Support

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log, glog

google-glog logging library have a Debug Mode in which the log messages are compiled away if NDEBUG is defined for performance reasons.

Does Boost.Log have something similar?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598149/enable-boost-log-only-on-debug